# Transforming code to multithread version

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following  problem:

- for example, I have 10 lists, each one has a link to some other lists, I would like to create a code to search elements in theses lists, I've already done this algorithm but sequentially, it start the search in the first list, then if the search is failed, it send messages for searching in lists that have a link with it (to the first one), at the end of the algorithm, he show the results as the number of lists visited and if he find the element or no.
- now, I want to transform it to be a parallel algorithm, at least a concurrent one using multi-threads:

  - to use threads for searching;
  - to start a search in the 10 lists at the same time;

Comment: Hi jojo, welcome to SO. If you post your code for the sequential version then someone should be able to help you to multithread it

Comment: I would use ExecutorService.submit() for a fixed size pool. To run all 10 at once, you will need 10 cores.  If you don't, it could be faster than what you have now but they won't all be running at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't change anything, you can consider your search read only. In that case, you probably don't need synchronization. If you want to have a fast search, don't use threads directly but use runnables and look for the appropriate classes. If you do work directly with threads, make sure that you don't exceed the number of processors.

Before going further, read into multi-threading. I would mention "Java Concurrency in Practice" as a (rather safe) recommendation. It's too easy to get wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all responses,

I  have just a Dual-Core, I would make a sort of a simulation of a parallel environment using threads, I would start a search simultaneously in for example 10 lists or Array-Lists, with each one (list) can generate an other number of search... 
I hope that you understand my goal...


Best regards, and thanks for every responses...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your problem statement if there is a sequential dependency between the searches in different lists, namely whether search results from the first list should take priority over those from the second list or not.

Assume there's no such dependency, so that any search result from any list is fine, then this is expressed in a very concise way as a speculative search in Ateji PX:

```
Object parallelSearch(Collection<List> lists)
{
  // start of parallel block
  [
    // create one parallel branch for each of the lists
    || (List list: lists) {

       // start searching lists in parallel
       Object result = search(list);

       // the first branch that finds a result returns it, 
       // thereby stopping all remaining parallel branches
       if(result != null) return result;
    }
  ]
}
```

The term "speculative" means that you run a number of searches in parallel although you know that you will use the result of only one of them. Then as soon as you have found a result in one of the searches, you want to stop all the remaining searches.

If you run this code on a 4-core machine, the Ateji PX runtime will schedule 4 parallel branches at a time in order to make the best use of the available parallel hardware.